# XMLHttpRequest has an invalid context error

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code:

```
<body><button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<script>
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
   var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
   rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
   rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
   rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
           callback(rawFile.responseText);
       }
   }
rawFile.send(null);
}

function myFunction(){
  document.write("<div id='cy'></div>");
  readTextFile("book.json", function(text){
        var data = JSON.parse(text);
        console.log("Something");
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```

This gives me the error:

> XMLHttpRequest has an invalid context

But if i comment `document.write("<div id='cy'></div>");` it works.
Someone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `document.write` in a loaded document implicitly called `document.open` which **destroys** the current document (which is the context to which the XHR object belongs) and creates a new one.

Comment: So why it works if i put `document.write("<div id='cy'></div>"); readTextFile("book.json", function(text){ var data = JSON.parse(text); console.log("Something"); }` outside the myFunction()???
@Quentin

Comment: Because then the document is *still loading*, it hasn't loaded.

Comment: Ok, so how can i do the same thing without having this error? @Quentin?

Comment: Use DOM instead of document.write

Comment: I need to do that inside myFunction(), if i use the DOM i have to write outside `<script></script>` @Quentin

Comment: No more so than if you used `document.write` (which would put the content immediately after the script element).